# Gatsby markdown URL / Link broken

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site with Markdown files that generate pages/urls. There are 2 types: products and blogs. The products work fine but when you try to go directly to a blog post page (from a link), no markdown appears.

https://www.squarepatch.io/Instructions/blog/        < ----- no markdown appears

However, if you navigate to the same page from within the site (site-map in the footer), the markdown appears and everything is fine.

Has anyone else run into this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related with some typo in your code, the URL you've provided has a blink between **i**nstructions and **I**nstructions (note the capitalization of the i) for a second (and the post can be seen while the blink occurs), check your naming components, templates, and paths.

Without providing any code, files, and sources it's difficult guess what's happening.

If you provide some information about your project structure I'll update the answer if I see something wrong.

Comment: Here's my rep if you want to take a look https://github.com/TrevPennington/squareflora I appreciate it.